# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{P(n)}$, where $P(n)$ is the partition function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-partitions

Is there a closed form for the following infinite series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{P(n)}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+...$$
where $P(n)$ is the partition function.

Comment: Interesting question. Does it come from some applications? Inverse symbolic calculator does not propose anything promising.

Comment: To be more precise, with $20$ digits [ISC](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) says "Wow, really found nothing".

Comment: See [OEIS A$078506$](http://oeis.org/A078506).